# Google AdWords out of stock script

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api, indexof

For our Google AdWords campaigns we use a script that checks if products are in stock. If a product is out of stock, it pauses the campaing. After running te script we get the following error:

I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot call method of "indexOf" of null. (line 54).

The part of the error is:

```js
 if(STRIP_QUERY_STRING) {
    if(url.indexOf('?')>=0) {
      url = url.split('?')[0];
    }
  }
  if(url.indexOf('{') >= 0) {
    //Let's remove the value track parameters
    url = url.replace(/\{[0-9a-zA-Z]+\}/g,'');
  }
  return url;
}
```

The full script is:

```js
/************************************
Script aan/uit advertenties
***********************************/
var URL_LEVEL = 'Ad'; // or Keyword
var ONLY_ACTIVE = false; // set to false for all ads or keywords
var CAMPAIGN_LABEL = 'automatisch'; // set this if you want to only check campaigns with this label
var STRIP_QUERY_STRING = true; // set this to false if the stuff that comes after the question mark is important
var WRAPPED_URLS = false; // set this to true if you use a 3rd party like Marin or Kenshoo for managing you account
// This is the specific text to search for 
// on the page that indicates the item 
// is out of stock.
var OUT_OF_STOCK_TEXT = 'adwords-niet-op-voorraad';
 
function main() {
  var alreadyCheckedUrls = {};
  var iter = buildSelector().get();
  while(iter.hasNext()) {
    var entity = iter.next();
    var url = cleanUrl(entity.getDestinationUrl());
    if(alreadyCheckedUrls[url]) {
      if(alreadyCheckedUrls[url] === 'out of stock') {
        entity.pause();
      } else {
        entity.enable();
      }
    } else {
      var htmlCode;
      try {
        htmlCode = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
      } catch(e) {
        Logger.log('There was an issue checking:'+url+', Skipping.');
        continue;
      }
      if(htmlCode.indexOf(OUT_OF_STOCK_TEXT) >= 0) {
        alreadyCheckedUrls[url] = 'out of stock';
        entity.pause();
      } else {
        alreadyCheckedUrls[url] = 'in stock';
        entity.enable();
      }
    }
    Logger.log('Url: '+url+' is '+alreadyCheckedUrls[url]);
  }
}
 
function cleanUrl(url) {
  if(WRAPPED_URLS) {
    url = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('https'));
    if(decodeURIComponent(url) !== url) {
      url = decodeURIComponent(url);
    }
  }
  if(STRIP_QUERY_STRING) {
    if(url.indexOf('?')>=0) {
      url = url.split('?')[0];
    }
  }
  if(url.indexOf('{') >= 0) {
    //Let's remove the value track parameters
    url = url.replace(/\{[0-9a-zA-Z]+\}/g,'');
  }
  return url;
}
 
function buildSelector() {
  var selector = (URL_LEVEL === 'Ad') ? AdWordsApp.ads() : AdWordsApp.keywords();
  selector = selector.withCondition('CampaignStatus != DELETED').withCondition('AdGroupStatus != DELETED');
  if(ONLY_ACTIVE) {
    selector = selector.withCondition('CampaignStatus = ENABLED').withCondition('Status = ENABLED');
    if(URL_LEVEL !== 'Ad') {
      selector = selector.withCondition('AdGroupStatus = ENABLED');
    }
  }
  if(CAMPAIGN_LABEL) {
    var label = AdWordsApp.labels().withCondition("Name = '"+CAMPAIGN_LABEL+"'").get().next();
    var campIter = label.campaigns().get();
    var campaignNames = [];
    while(campIter.hasNext()) {
      campaignNames.push(campIter.next().getName());
    }
    selector = selector.withCondition("CampaignName IN ['"+campaignNames.join("','")+"']");
  }
  return selector;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `getDestinationUrl()` to retrieve the ad's/keyword's URL, but destination URLs have been deprecated in Adwords since about a year, that's why this method returns `null` which means you call `cleanUrl()` with `null` as argument causing the error that you listed.

In order to make the script work, I'd guess you have to use `.urls().getFinalUrl()` instead of `getDestinationUrl()`.

Comment: Many thanks for this solution. Deprecated since about a year? That makes me feel kinda dumb. Lucky for me i was asked to look into this just yesterday. Anyway, thanks a lot. Do you have any link to a Google library for functions like this one? I can't find a good one.

Comment: Yeah, I think the original destination URLs were migrated to Final URLs in July 2015 or thereabouts. As for documentation, here's a good starting point: https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/reference/adwordsapp/adwordsapp_ad